# Reference to an object is not updating the object

Tags: c#

Hi I am working with code that looks something like this .

```
class A
{
    Custom objA;

    public A()
    {
        //Assign some value to objA;
        B obj = new B(objA);
    }
}

class B
{
    Custom objB;

    public B(Custom obj)
    {
        this.objB = obj;
    }

    public void Func()
    {
        this.objB = null;
    }
}
```

where `Custom` is a custom nullable type.

Now, as per my knowledge, the `objA` must be updated to have value null, whenever I am calling the `Func()` of `class B`. However that's not what is happening.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: What IS happening?

Comment: `B obj = B(objA);` you mean `B obj = new B(objA);` ? and also show us how you are creating objects and calling `Func` method

Comment: In the constructir of the class A you need to  use new to instantiate an object B

Comment: @Amit that was a typing mistake on my side, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, on line 5, you have a syntax error. You could do `B obj = new B(objA)` if you are trying to create a new instance of `B`. But I can only guess.

What it seems like you are trying to do is modify `objA` by having passed it into a new object of type `B`, storing it in a field, and then modifying the field. The problem is that what you are storing is a copy of a reference to `objA`. When you do `this.objB = null`, you are modifying the field `objB` to have a new reference (`null`), but you have not done anything to the field `objA` which is a member of the instance of class `A`.

Comment: I didn't get you on "but you have not done anything to the field objA which is a member of the instance of class A" as he is doing `this.objB = obj;` where `obj` is supposed to be classA's Custom obj's ref

Comment: @Amit: that copies a reference to `objA` into `objB`. But `objA` and `objB` are two separate fields. Modifying one via `=` does not modify the other. It's like if you had two variables in a method: `int x = 3; int y = x; x = 4;`. That would not result in `x` having the value 4.

Comment: Yeah i got that now what you are saying. however you can update answer with proper example and little easy way ! for the sake of PO's understanding.  +1

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this is the code that you're asking about in your question:

```
class A
{
    Custom objCustom;

    public A()
    {
        objCustom = new Custom();
        B objB = new B(objCustom);
        objB.Func();
    }
}

class B
{
    Custom objCustom;

    public B(Custom objCustom)
    {
        this.objCustom = objCustom;
    }

    public void Func()
    {
        this.objCustom = null;
    }
}
```

This compiles and has a fairly consistent naming convention.

The issue you have the with the `Custom objCustom` field in both class `A` and `B` is that even though they both reference the same instance before the call to `.Func()` you need to understand that the `Custom objCustom` field is just a reference to the object, and not the object itself. So when you call `.Func()` you are assigning a new reference to the `Custom objCustom` in `objB`, but you're not doing anything to the reference in `objA`. It still points to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

In function `Func` you assign `null` to the field of `B` object (not `A` object) so after this function call field `objB` of `B` object is not pointing to any object of type `Custom`, but `objA` field of `A` object is still pointing to a single `Custom` object.

Here is example of code, where `Func` will change `objA` field of `A` object:

```
class A
{
    public Custom objA = new Custom();

    public A()
    {
        B obj = new B(this);
        B.Func(); // after this, objA field will be null
    }
}

class B
{
    А obj;

    public B(А obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void Func()
    {
        obj.objA = null;
    }
}
```

Also note:

1. When you create an `A` object, its `objA` field is `null`, so in constructor of `A` you actually calling `B obj = new B(null);`, so its `objB` field is `null` too.
2. After `A` object is constructed, object `obj` of type `B` will be disposed, since you don't hold a reference to it, so you not calling a `Func` function in your example.

Comment: You might want to re-read the question again. Your first two points seem to not make sense based on what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I upvoted in spite of 1. and 2. It seems like the code is probably what OP wants.

Comment: @siride - The OP's code is not very clear, but I don't think it is what vasily has done here. I think the use of the name `objA` was misleading in the OP's question and more so in vasily's answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right. 1. and 2. is actually a sidenotes and should not be in the begining of my answer. I fix this.

Comment: @siride i think your answer is solving concern where OP was confused, while this answer is not explaining what OP was doing wrong instead it it trying to provide an alternate solution.